# Can a differential ADC's low pass RC filter be simplified to use less components

Tags: filter, low-pass

I am making a circuit using an ADS1115 analog to digital converter to read an AC signal using the differential mode of the IC, the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1115.pdf#page=38) recommends that I add a low - pass RC filter:

[image]

Can the circuit be simplfied to use lesser amount of components? Like the resistor combined to a single 200 ohm resistor. My rational on why I think it is possible because the formula in the datasheet just adds them.

$$f_C = \frac{1}{2\pi(R5+R6)C_{Diff}}$$

Comment: Fewer components not less components.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope.  You can't combine the resistors.  That's a filter for a differential signal.  If you combine the two resistors into one, then it is no longer a differential filter - it won't work right.

Answer (score 4):

C1 and C2, together with R1 and R2, filter out *common mode* noise.

R1 and R2, together with C3, filter out *differential mode* noise, without turning it into common mode noise.

You can't filter out both common-mode and differential-mode noise, and at independent frequencies, without using those five components.